# removing group while doing CSV export in JasperReports 4.0.5

Tags: jasper-reports

I am using the JasperReports 4.0.5. Trying to suppress group footer and headers while exporting to CSV.
I've tried the using of
***`net.sf.jasperreports.export.{format}.exclude.origin.{suffix}.{arbitrary_name}`*** property.

It didn't work.
Any suggestions?

TU

Comment: Did you add the property to the jrxml file? Could you post the header (with all report's properties) of your jrxml file.

Comment: net.sf.jasperreports.export.csv.exclude.origin.group.1=GroupExpensesFooter. This is the only property I have in my Jrxml file. Other than the default report properties.

Comment: <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.csv.exclude.origin.group.1" value="GroupExpensesFooter" />

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For hiding only the *groupHeader* band you should add this two properties (both lines) to the *jrxml* file, for example:

```xml
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.csv.exclude.origin.band.1" value="groupHeader"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.csv.exclude.origin.group.1" value="GroupExpenses"/>
```

For hiding both *groupHeader* and *groupFooter* bands you should add all this properties to *jrxml* file:

```xml
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.csv.exclude.origin.band.1" value="groupHeader"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.csv.exclude.origin.group.1" value="GroupExpenses"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.csv.exclude.origin.band.2" value="groupFooter"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.csv.exclude.origin.group.2" value="GroupExpenses"/>
```

In both samples the group name is ***GroupExpenses***.

```xml
<group name="GroupExpenses">
```

---

For more details look at [How can I suppress page headers and footers when exporting to XLS?](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/jasperreports-library-faq#How_can_I_suppress_page_headers_and_footers_when_exporting_to_XLS) topic.

Comment: Thanks Alex. I tried that in the Jrxml file and it doesn't work.