# How do I Export to CSV Without Header & Footer repeating?

Tags: jasper-reports, export-to-csv

I want to export to CSV with the Header and Footer only showing once

```
The current output:
Name   Address Hobby
AAA    US      XXXXX
BBB    UK      XXXXX
(Footer)
Name   Address Hobby
CCC    ID      XXXXX
DDD    CC      XXXXX
(Footer)
Name   Address Hobby
EEE    SA      XXXXX
FFF    ZM      XXXXX
(Footer)

The desired output:
Name   Address Hobby
AAA    US      XXXXX
BBB    UK      XXXXX
CCC    ID      XXXXX
DDD    CC      XXXXX
EEE    SA      XXXXX
FFF    ZM      XXXXX
(Footer)
```

So how do I get the Header and footer to only show once ?

**EDIT:**

Footer looks like

Version : 1.0.0
AcademicProgramBusinessEntityCentreDoma                             Execution Time : 00:00:00.00
/NWU/StudentInformation/AcademicProgramDevelopment                  Build: v1.0.9 - Dev

Comment: Can you post the *jrxml* file? About what *Footer* are you talking?

Comment: Edited the post so you can see footer, And I'm making changes to the Jasper code not jrxml's else I will have to change ALL the jrxml's

Comment: Is it *Group Footer* or *Column Footer* or *Page Footer*? `And I'm making changes to the Jasper code` - Are you talking about *Java* code? Are you using *jrxml* files or you are generate report dynamically with help of *Java* code?

Comment: its a page footer & page header that I only want at Top & bottom, & Yes, I am making changes to the Java code & the reports are saved in jrxml files (when I export to Excel the export works the way I want, but no luck with CSV)

Comment: If you have a *jrxml* - you should post it, if you have the *Java* code - you should post it

Comment: Did you check the *csv* in basic text editor (in *Notepad*, for example)? Did you see the repeating data from footer there?

Comment: I'm not going to post Thousands upon Thousands of lines of code, most of the classes need the whole jasper install of function, anyone that has the Clean Jasper code (or modified) already has the code & It won't make a difference to open it in Notepad ?, Just opened it in Notepad, looks exactly the same

Comment: May be this help you: [removing group while doing CSV export in JasperReports 4.0.5](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8987921/876298) & [JasperReports: hide textfield when not HTML view](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8044930/876298).

Comment: Thx Alex, 1st link is what i want :D !! but I need to exclude page header & footer not Group header & footer , any idea how to do this ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use **net.sf.jasperreports.export.{format}.exclude.origin.{suffix}.{arbitrary_name}**(see the http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/config.reference.html page for details) property for excluding bands (*Page Header* and *Page Footer* in your case) for exporter.

The sample:

The input data, csv file (datasource):

```
AAA,US,XXXXX
BBB,UK,XXXXX
CCC,ID,XXXXX
DDD,CC,XXXXX
EEE,SA,XXXXX
FFF,ZM,XXXXX
```

The *jrxml* file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="exclude_band_for_csv" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="120" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0" uuid="daaa60dc-b91b-4e9b-bbc0-6189af985ef9">
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.csv.exclude.origin.band.1" value="pageHeader"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.csv.exclude.origin.band.2" value="pageFooter"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="Name" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="Address" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="Hobby" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="35" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="9da294e6-b5b7-489f-9469-7edb539315da" x="117" y="0" width="380" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="14"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Page Header]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </pageHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="6a615d39-86f1-4a74-8ae7-4f8ca8e19afe" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Name}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="df0929d2-34c0-4561-ab98-e6e5ce37fd11" x="100" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Address}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="675381d8-57b3-427f-88e4-ec4725ea3462" x="200" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Hobby}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="45" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="9da294e6-b5b7-489f-9469-7edb539315da" x="127" y="10" width="380" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="14"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Page Footer]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </pageFooter>
</jasperReport>
```

The report's design in *iReport*:

[image: Report's design in iReport]

The result of *JRPdfExporter* will be:

[image: The result of generating the report in *PDF* format]

Both bands are present in *PDF* file

The result of *JRCsvExporter* will be (the output *csv* file):

```
AAA,US,XXXXX
BBB,UK,XXXXX
CCC,ID,XXXXX
DDD,CC,XXXXX
EEE,SA,XXXXX
FFF,ZM,XXXXX
```

Both bands are absent in *CSV* file.

As you can see I've excluded two bands (*Page Header* and *Page Footer*) only for *JRCsvExporter*.

---

For more details you can also see this post: [JasperReports: hide textfield when not HTML view](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8044930/876298)

Answer (score 3):

to prevent column header repeating you can use following property:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.export.{format}.exclude.origin.keep.first.{suffix}.{arbitrary_name}
```

for example to avoid column header repeating in csv you write:

```
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.csv.exclude.origin.keep.first.band.1" value="columnHeader"/>
```

https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/how-can-i-suppress-page-headers-and-footers-when-exporting-xls