# How do I omit the grouping function (but include the grouping value as a column) in a Jasper report (CSV export vs HTML layout)?

Tags: csv, jasper-reports

I have a Jasper Reports (version 6.4) report that uses a `<group>`. Very simple (say HTML) example, with car maker as the **group** expression:

```
Car maker: BMW
==============
    Model     Price
    --------  -------
    1 Series  20000
    X2        30000
    Z4        50000

Car maker: Kia
==============
    Model     Price
    --------  -------
    Rio       17000
    Sportage  24000

Car maker: VW
==============
    Model     Price
    --------  -------
    Golf      19000
```

**My question: is it possible to use the same report specification, but for exporting another format (e.g. CSV) the group value becomes another column, e.g.:**

```
Maker, Model, Price
BMW, "1 Series", 10000
BMW, X2, 20000
BMW, Z4, 40000
Kia, Rio, 17000
Kia, Sportage, 24000
VW, Golf, 19000
```

If so, how?

A colleague that knows Oracle Reports claims the latter can do this, so Jasper should also be able to.

**Note** this question is *not the same* as simply removing the group band, which is answered in multiple places e.g. [How do I Export to CSV Without Header & Footer repeating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17426115/how-do-i-export-to-csv-without-header-footer-repeating) and [removing group while doing CSV export in JasperReports 4.0.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8987921/removing-group-while-doing-csv-export-in-jasperreports-4-0-5). **Added:** The solution from these posts remove the "group" band, but do not add the value to the datatable. I.e., it results in a table like

```
Model, Price
"1 Series", 10000
X2, 20000
...
```

while I need a table like:

```
Maker, Model, Price
BMW, "1 Series", 10000
BMW, X2, 20000
...
```

**Again: this is NOT A DUPLICATE of the already mentioned questions, as those questions only refer to the removal of header row bands. *In addition to removing the grouping headers,* I *also* need the value that would have been shown in the header, to now be shown on each (applicable) row of the remaining data table. If this can be done, I don't know how and can not see it in the other linked questions.**

Comment: Did you try solution from posts you mentioned? Why this solution (using of  net.sf.jasperreports.export.{format}.exclude.origin.{suffix}.{arbitrary_name} property) is not working at your case?

Comment: @AlexK: no. I updated the question under Note to explain what happens.

Comment: You can add elements you need and hide it for another format